# Redirect parent page to specified url on Submit inside fancybox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

i am using fancybox and after submiting my form i want to redirtect my parent page to some specified url i am using fancybox as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('[id*=addnewRequest]').fancybox({
                'width': 760,
                'height': 540,
                'padding': 0,
                'margin': 0,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'scrolling': 'auto',
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'type': 'iframe',
                'centerOnScroll': true,
                'onClosed': function () {

                    if ($.redirTo != null && $.redirTo.length > 0){

                        window.location.replace($.redirTo);
                    }

                    else {
                        parent.location.reload(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

and after submiting my form i am using below register script where  'redirectTo'  is url where i want my parent page will redirect

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "add", "parent.jQuery.redirTo='" + redirectTo + "'; parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();", true);
```

Now how my parent page will redirect to perticular url.Any idea?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After submiting your form you can direct call the `window.top.location.href` with the new url as:

```
window.top.location.href = "http://www.urltogo.com/pagetomove.aspx";
```

and avoid to send parameters on the parent and from there make the redirect.

Here is an example (I add 5 second delay to have the time to see it)

http://jsfiddle.net/u6whQ/3/   or  http://jsfiddle.net/u6whQ/4/

Your line will probably be as:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), "add", "window.top.location.href ='" + redirectTo + "'; parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();", true);
```

Comment: happy new year to you too.

Comment: My fancy box open working in all browser except IE . when i use IE it directly open the page in present window in place of fancybox

Comment: @GurbaxSinghBhangal try on ie only `top.location.href` to see if works

Comment: @GurbaxSinghBhangal also check if the `window.top.location` or `top.location` works on IE (with out the href)

Comment: @GurbaxSinghBhangal For some reason on my IE (ver 8) works just fine.